# Finding distance of two circles in python

Tags: python

I am learning python programming.

[image]

There are two circles and they both have their own centers c1 and c2. Also any point x1,y1 lies in circle1 and x2,y2 lies in circle2. We need to create three class `Circle,Line,Points`. It is mandatory and we need to find distance between two circle in **Circle class**. Distance between two circle is given by `r1+r2` of two circles. I tried to find the distance but I am getting error:

```
import math 
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
     
class Line:
       
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        self.p1=p1
        self.p2=p2

class circle:
    
    def __init__(self,l1,l2):
        self.l1=l1
        self.l2=l2
        
    def calculatedistance(self):
        r1=math.sqrt((self.l1.p1.x-self.l1.p2.x)^2+(self.l1.p2.x-self.l1.p2.x)^2)
        r2=math.sqrt((self.l2.p1.y-self.l2.p2.y)^2+(self.l2.p2.y-self.l2.p2.y)^2)
        total_distance=r1+r2
        return total_distance 

center1=Point(1,2)
point1=Point(3,4)
center2=Point(2,3)
point2=Point(5,6)

line1=Line(center1,point1)
line2=Line(center2,point2)

circle1=circle(line1,line2)
circle1.calculatedistance()
```

I am getting error `ValueError: math domain error`.Is there any better way to code rather than mine?

Comment: In python, the symbol `^` is bitwise XOR operator. To square a number, you can use the `**` operator.

Comment: Also, take a closer look at the whole error message, it should tell you exactly on which line the problem happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is bitwise XOR operator. Instead, you should use `**2` to take the square of a number.

```py
import math 
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
     
class Line:
       
    def __init__(self,p1,p2):
        self.p1=p1
        self.p2=p2

class circle:
    
    def __init__(self,l1,l2):
        self.l1=l1
        self.l2=l2
        
    def calculatedistance(self):
        r1=math.sqrt((self.l1.p1.x-self.l1.p2.x)**2+(self.l1.p2.x-self.l1.p2.x)**2)
        r2=math.sqrt((self.l2.p1.y-self.l2.p2.y)**2+(self.l2.p2.y-self.l2.p2.y)**2)
        total_distance=r1+r2
        return total_distance 

center1=Point(1,2)
point1=Point(3,4)
center2=Point(2,3)
point2=Point(5,6)

line1=Line(center1,point1)
line2=Line(center2,point2)

circle1=circle(line1,line2)
circle1.calculatedistance()
```

> output : 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `**2` to get the square of a number. Compute `r1` and `r2` using:

```
r1=math.sqrt((self.l1.p1.x-self.l1.p2.x)**2+(self.l1.p2.x-self.l1.p2.x)**2)
r2=math.sqrt((self.l2.p1.y-self.l2.p2.y)**2+(self.l2.p2.y-self.l2.p2.y)**2)
```